# Magento: share db between 2 vhost

Tags: database, magento, share

i have 2 vhost:

dev.example.com, dev1.example.com

and i don't want to have 2 db, but only 1.

So i connect both vh to the same db, but when i go to dev1.example.com i redirected to dev.example.com.

I think due to "web/secure/url" and "web/unsecure/url" that i setted as dev.example.com.

I'm trying to make a switching in the code, but don't find the point where magento set the url.

Have you some idea or done some switch code to make this behaviour?

thx
Luca

EDIT: the vhosts have a different document root, they are 2 different developer environment.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must create 2 differents "Website" in the Backoffice of magento (menu System / Manages Stores).

Next, updates theirs respective web/unsecure/url and web/secure/url.

Next in your virtualhost, you'll have to modify the MAGE_RUN_CODE Env variable for each of your domains in order to Magento to recognize which website it must point ..

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/navigation/multiple-website-setup for details

Comment: i don't want another website, because so i modify the store structure! i want the same db for 2 developer environment to avoid to create another identic db.

Comment: So the 2 environnement have to share the same domain name but can be hosted on a different Machine (or virtual machine) : different IP address

Comment: this is nice! but if i have X developer environment i have to make X vhost on different machine? it is impossible to make! :(
i have to make some code switch that analyze the $_SERVER['http_host'] and use the correct base url...i think this is the right way! :)